# A way to capture an html snippet into a variable inside a template

Tags: django, django-templates

I would like a tag which would allow me to capture everything inside of it into a variable. Something like the following:

```
{% capture_to_var my_html %}
    <a href="{% url foo %}">{{ var }}</a>
{% endcapture_to_var %}
```

After which the variable `my_html` would contain an html snippet with the `<a href...`

This could be very handy when instantiating sub-templates via `include` (e.g. `{% include 'sub-item.html' with complex_html=my_html %}`). Django provides a way to do this via template inheritance, but that requires creating a separate file for each snippet, which is not nice when one has too many of them. Is there any way to do without that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom template tag, for example, this one:

https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/545/